# Get distinct values from collection with another field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this query which returns distinct test ids from my collection

```
Model.find().distinct('TestId', (err, data) => { console.log(data); }
```

> [ 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 ]

These all values has `TestName` as well and now I want to return them as well. Something like this:

> [ {TestId: 1, TestName: 'tname'}... ]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`distinct` doesn't support adding other fields to the output, but you can do this with a simple `aggregate` pipeline:

```
Model.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$TestId', TestName: {$first: '$TestName'}}}])
```

This will group the docs by `TestId` and include the `TestName` field from the first doc in each group.

Comment: distinct test_ids??

Comment: @wrangler Sorry, I don't follow what you're asking

Comment: Dont know much about aggregate but does the above query returns **distinct** test ids??

Comment: @wrangler Yes, `$group` returns one record per unique value in the specified `_id`.

Comment: okay so you are basically grouping all documents with respect to their `_ids` and then returning the testname associated with the first document in the group.

Comment: @wrangler Right; I updated the answer to add some detail on that.